# Microsoft Word Read-Only Document - Avoid Unwanted Tab Space

Tags: microsoft-word, read-only, indentation, docx, autoindent

I have a read-only Microsoft Word (docx) document that has (in addition to explanatory read-only text) a few editable forms. In one of these forms, there are two columns. Each column has a non-editable label. To the right of each label there is an editable form input.

```
Name: __________  Title: ___________
                  Address: ____________
                  Phone #: ______________
```

You can see how "Name", "Title", "Address" and "Phone #" are the uneditable labels, and to the right of them there is a form input.

Now, my problem is that when I enter a name of a certain length in the "Name" input, it causes the "Title" label to indent if it reaches a certain length. This causes the "Title" label to be uneven with the labels in the same column below it. It is a professional document and this looks quite unprofessional.

My question is, how can I avoid the tab-indent on "Title"? There is plenty of space between the "Name" label and the "Title" input. The character input does not run into the "Title label". But for some reason Word sees fit to indent "Title". Keep in mind that this is a read-only document and I am constrained by this fact.

Thanks,
ktm

Answer (score 0):

I know you can make pdf documents with editable forms. Learn how to do it here:

> http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/206746.html